# How to show that the vectors of $\ker \phi$ are linearly indipendent to other vectors in a orthogonal basis with respect to $\phi$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

How can I show that, given a symmetric bilinear form in a finite dimensional vector space $V$ $\phi : V\times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then the vectors of the basis of $\ker \phi$ (which I assume that are **always** contained in **any** **orthoghonal** basis with respect to $\phi$) are linearly independent to the other vectors in the basis?

The problem is this: If I want to find an orthogonal basis of $V$ with respect to $\phi$ and $\phi$ is **semidefinite positive** I can consider the vector of a basis of $\ker \phi$, complete the basis to a basis of $V$ and then use Gram-Schmidt for the vectors of the built basis that do not belong to $\ker\phi$. I can do that because all the isotropic vectors are surely contained in $\ker\phi$ therefore the process works and what I find are vector surely orthogonal to the vectors of $\ker \phi$ (that are orthogonal to any other vector of $V$).

But then to be sure that what I have found is a basis of $V$ I must prove that the vectors in it are linearly indipendent and here is the problem.

How can I show that the vectors of $\ker \phi$ are linearly indipendent from the others?

Thanks in advice

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is more or less automatic; consider the image of the candidate basis under the projection $V \to V / \ker \phi$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I can't see it, I guess that the projection of these vectors is theyrself, except for the vectors in $ker\phi$ that give $\vec{o}$, is this enough to conclude that they are linearly indipendent?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a basis of $V$ part of which is a basis for $\ker\phi$, then what you have is a splitting $V = \ker\phi\oplus V_1$ for some $V_1$. By construction Gram-Schmidt will give you an orthogonal basis for $V_1$ as $\phi|_{V_1}$ is **necessarily** positive-definite. You now have a basis for $\ker\phi$ and an orthogonal basis for $V_1$; because $V = \ker\phi\oplus V_1$ (this fact has not changed, nor should it for any reason) and because $\ker\phi$ is orthogonal to everything, smashing these bases together gives you an orthogonal basis for $V$.